# How to reset radio_button.setButtonDrawable(null)

Tags: java, android

I want to toggle the appearance of circle of the radio button. I am able to make it disappear by setting radio_btn.setButtonDrawable(null) but I don't know how to bring it back.

```
    rbGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            checkAnswerRadio();
        }
    });

private void checkAnswerRadio(){
   rb1.setButtonDrawable(null);
}
```

Comment: you can save it in sharedpreference or global variable in the onCheckedChanged
right before you setButtonDrawable(null)
drawable = getButtonDrawable;

Comment: It's not working below API 21.

Comment: posted the answer for api < 21 as well , please check it out

Comment: Try using `AppCompatRadioButton` and the use `getButtonDrawable()`

Answer (score 0):

You can set it back like doing :

to set as default off:

```
 rb1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.radiobutton_off_background)
```

to set as default on:

```
rbOne.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.radiobutton_on_background)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in sharedpreference or global variable in the onCheckedChanged right before you setButtonDrawable(null) drawable = rb1.getButtonDrawable();

for API < 21 use

`ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.YourDrawable);`

and you can set

`rb1.setButtonDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.YourDrawable));` which is the default drawable you can put in your res/drawable folder